# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Scope should be defined when using a key file

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow, dataflow

Problem : While running dataflow job using airflow ,i am getting below error, is it related to the keypath which we provide in connection. If yes what should be the correct path. Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run 

result = task_copy.execute(context=context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 114, in execute
self.jar = bucket_helper.google_cloud_to_local(self.jar)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 229, in google_cloud_to_local
file_size = self._gcs_hook.download(bucket_id, object_id, local_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py", line 58, in download
service = self.get_conn()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py", line 43, in get_conn
http_authorized = self._authorize()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 84, in _authorize
raise AirflowException('Scope should be defined when using a key file.')
AirflowException: Scope should be defined when using a key file.
[2017-06-13 20:05:45,165] {models.py:1433} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2017-06-13 20:05:45,174] {models.py:1462} ERROR - Scope should be defined when using a key file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
args.func(args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 585, in test
ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 114, in execute
self.jar = bucket_helper.google_cloud_to_local(self.jar)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 229, in google_cloud_to_local
file_size = self._gcs_hook.download(bucket_id, object_id, local_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py", line 58, in download
service = self.get_conn()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py", line 43, in get_conn
http_authorized = self._authorize()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 84, in _authorize
raise AirflowException('Scope should be defined when using a key file.')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Scope should be defined when using a key file.
```

Can anybody please help me with it ?.Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the "Scopes" field of the connection in Airflow. In the Web UI, go to `Admin > Connections` in the top menu and click the edit link for `google_cloud_default`. For GCS, the list of scopes can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes). The most general to use is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`.